# Change permalinks - htaccess code needed

Tags: php, .htaccess, blogs, permalinks

I have a blog (wordpress version 3.01) which has custom based permalinks in the following format: `/%category%/%postname%/`. For example, `blog.com/category/post-name/`.

I need to change permalinks to "Day and name" `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` (my Theme requires that to work properly).

What do I need to write in my .htaccess file to make the old permalinks 301 to redirect to the new ones?

My site is 9 months old and has about 500 articles.

---

Example

/%category%/%postname%/  to /%postname%/

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ http://www.mydomain.com/$2

**My case is to get this**

/%category%/%postname%/ to /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

RedirectMatch 301 ???????????

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this with an `.htaccess` file as the rewrite feature (RewriteMap) which could do this doesn't work in a `.htaccess` context.  However, since you've got a closed list and therefore a fixed list of categories, it is simple to map these to a common redirector script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule ^(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4)/.*?/$ redirector.php?cat=$1&post=$2 [L,QSA]
```

(extending the cat list to be a complete list of categories).  Then `redirector.php` is a standard redirector pattern.  You simply query your Wordpress D/B to determine the YMD for the post to issue a

```
$server  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header( "Location: HTTP://$server/$year/$month/$day/$postName/", true, 302 );
```

before exiting.

Comment: Hi Terry, If I understand you right, 1) I put RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /  in my .htaccess file. 2) Make a file redirector.php, where I paste $server  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header( "Location: HTTP://$server/$year/$month/$day/$postName/", true, 302 );  Sorry, I am not so good at this,

Comment: Yup, the Rewrite lines go in your htaccess file.  The issue that yuo now have is that if someone types "`http://yourdomain/wranting/Why-do-I-hate-myself/`", say and this article was published Jan 2, 2012 then you need to direct to "`http://yourdomain/2012/01/02/Why-do-I-hate-myself/`".  Where do you lookup your YMD details for each article?  You either use the Wordpress D/B or you have an array of article publication dates hard-wired into the script.  I'll update it to show you how to do the latter :-)

Comment: Ok, Thanks:-) Looking forward

Comment: I've just thought about this. I started to sketch out a solution, but you need to be able to do minimal php scripting to understand this.  If you don't have this then the correct answer is "sorry, but you can't do this without scripting.  However, I've retagged the post to add PHP and maybe someone else can provide a standard workaround.

Comment: Thank you TerryE, Yes, fact is my PHP skill is minimal, understand some basics. Looking forward